# Output a new dataframe successively with new rows from text input with Shiny App (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to populate a data frame successively by adding a new row and then rendering the latest updated table using shiny inputs and outputs.  A user types in a "recommendation" in a textfield and this needs to be added to the data frame every time they click the action button. The user should be able to add as many rows as needed. This is my code:

server.R

```
# here I am using observe and isolate to ensure the action button only applies to the textfield in question

values <- reactiveValues(textInput = NA)

observe({

    if(input$actionButton > 0) {

        values$textInput <- isolate(input$textInput)

    }

})

# here is the output to render the table. Note that there is a function called "addRec" which brings in the current data frame with existing recommendations and the most recently typed recommendation from the text input

 output$table <- renderTable({

  p <- addRec(currentFrame, values$textInput)
  p

})
```

My ui.R shows the table as usual

```
htmlOutput("table")
```

And here is the function I use for adding a new row to the data frame. It takes in the currently existing data frame, adds a row with the new textinput and some other values, uses binding to create the new data frame, and then returns the newly formed frame.

```
addRec <- function(currentFrame, newRecommendation) {

newRecommendation <- c(newRecommendation, 11, 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low')

lFinal <- list(currentFrame, newRecommendation)
newFrame <- do.call("rbind", lFinal)

return(newFrame)
```

}

You can see that in my server.R file the output$table recursively adds the most recent table to the function.  But all I get is the same table being returned with no new rows. And when the user types in the recommendation in the textfield it just updates the last row in real time. I need a new data frame outputted each time with each new recommendation.

Comment: I don't see a place in  your code where the new updated dataframe is stored. The addRec is happening in the renderTable(), maybe is should happen outside of that function.

Comment: Yes good point.  So I tried playing around with save(newFrame, file="newFrame.Rda") to save the newly created dataframe and then somehow load this saved one into the next function call.  But I still get the same dataframe output.

Comment: Awesome got it...so yes I had to put the save(newFrame, file="newFrame.Rda") in the function and then the load("newFrame.Rda") in the outPut in the ui.R.  Thank you for the direction!

Comment: Glad it worked - you should write up an answer to your question and accept this as I think other folks might have a similar issue.